# json variable passing into <object> data parameter issue

Tags: php, html, json, variables

Trying to pass a file path location into the data="" of an html .

Here's the code in php that I am pulling from:

```
$filedatetime = date ("m-d-o_His");

// Save XFDF array to file
$result_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "\\results";
$xfdf_filename = $filedatetime . '.xfdf';
$xfdf_file_path = $result_path . "\\" . $xfdf_filename;
//$toBePassed = "results\\" . $xfdf_filename;
$toBePassed = $xfdf_filename;
```

and here's the json_encode call:

```
<object type="application/vnd.adobe.xfdf" data=<?php echo json_encode($toBePassed) ?> width="300" height="200"></object>
```

The file that is being generated is in a results folder, so I am trying to literally add "results/" to the front of the php variable. You can see that I tried to do it, but since php requires two backslashes, when I pass it, it comes out: "results\\10-15-2013_112852.xfdf". I'm sure at which point I can add the string to the front of the variable name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Please comment if there is still a better way, thanks!

```
<object id="XFDFElement" type="application/vnd.adobe.xfdf"></object>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strPath = "results/" + <?php echo json_encode($xfdf_filename) ?>;
    document.getElementById("XFDFElement").data = strPath;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
data="<?php echo json_encode($xfdf_filename); ?>"
```

(Note the quotation marks around the php tags - otherwise HTML will ignore the invalid attribute definition)

Comment: Oops, SO removed the php tags from my answer. Anyway try wrapping the php tag in quotes in your HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<object id="XFDFElement" type="application/vnd.adobe.xfdf" data="results/<?=json_encode($xfdf_filename)?>" width="300" height="200"></object>
```

Shorter and easier :)